# CCPanZoomController + Tappable Sprites

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a zoomable and pan-able map for my game (using CCPanZoomController) . Within this map I would like to have a tappable sprite, and when it is tapped, "do something"…

I can get the two things to work perfectly in separate projects, however when I try to combine them, nothing happens when I tap my sprite.

I have included an image to demonstrate further:
[image: Demo Of What I Want]

```
//in my init section


        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

            mapBase = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"MapBase.png"];
            mapBase.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
            [self addChild:mapBase z:-10];

            gym = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Gym.png"];
            gym.scale = 0.3;
            gym.position = ccp(1620, 250);
            [self addChild:gym z:1];

            CGRect boundingRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 2499, 1753);
            _controller = [[CCPanZoomController controllerWithNode:self] retain];
            _controller.boundingRect = boundingRect;
            _controller.zoomOutLimit = _controller.optimalZoomOutLimit;
            _controller.zoomInLimit = 2.0f;
            [_controller enableWithTouchPriority:1 swallowsTouches:YES];
//end of init

    -(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
    {
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self
                                                                  priority:0 swallowsTouches:NO];
    }

    -(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        CGPoint touchPoint1 = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(gym.boundingBox, touchPoint1)) return YES;

        return NO;

    }

    -(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        CGPoint touchPoint2 = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(gym.boundingBox, touchPoint2)){
            CCLOG(@"SPRITE HAS BEEN TAPPED");
        }
    }
```

I want to beable to zoom in/out and pan the wholemap (including the ‘Gym’ sprite).
And if the sprite 'Gym' is tapped by the user, then i would like to “do something”.

If anyone can figure this out, I would be extremely grateful!
Thanks.